# Cypress reutrns 302 instead of 200

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, cypress, http-status-code-302, http-status-code-200

I was trying to test sign-in page of our app. I am using cypress to test Vuejs frontend works with AspNet Api. When I click on the signin button on chrome it makes following requests and visits the homepage "localhost:44389"

[first request from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4SnN.png)

[second request from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MozGG.png)

if I want to simulate it on cypress it sends same request but get 302 from second request instead of 200.

[first request from Cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRTaQ.png)

[second request from Cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5xY6.png)

Can someone help me to find out the problem?

```
Cypress.Commands.add('IdentityServerAPILogin', (email, password) => {
  
  console.log("SERVER_URL is called. Server: " + Cypress.env('SERVER_URL'));
  
  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: Cypress.env('SERVER_URL'),
    failOnStatusCode: false,
    headers: {
      'Cookie': '...coookies...'
    }
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status == 401){
        console.log ("Check for NOnce");
        console.dir(response, { depth: null });
        const requestURL = response.allRequestResponses[1]["Request URL"]
        console.dir(requestURL, { depth: null })
        //const signInPage = (response.redirects[0]).replace('302: ', '');
        const signInPage = (response.redirects[1]).replace('302: ', '');
        console.log("signInPage:" + signInPage);
        const nOnceObj = response.allRequestResponses[0]["Response Headers"];
        console.dir(nOnceObj, { depth: null });
        const nOnce = nOnceObj["set-cookie"][0];
        console.log("Nonce:" + nOnce);
        cy.visit({
          method: 'GET',
          url: signInPage,
          failOnStatusCode: false,
          headers: {
            //'Cookie': nOnce
          }
        })
        // TODO: Create all needed tests later to test sign in
        cy.get('#username').type(email)
        cy.get('#password').type(password)
        // TODO: Waiting for to click signIn button. When I call the click() method I get infinite loop!!
        cy.get('.ping-button')
        // .click()
        //  .then((response_login) => {
        //     console.log("Status REsponse_Login: "+ response_login);
        //     console.dir(response_login, { depth: null });
        //     if (response_login.status == 401){
        //     cy.visit(Cypress.env('SERVER_URL'))  
        //     }     
        //   })
      }else
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('SERVER_URL'))             
    })  
  console.log("vorbei");
});
```

Just figured out Cypress is not able to get Cookies from `.../signin-oidc`, because there is an error as in the photo below

[image: SameSite=Lax Error]

Asking kindly for a solution. I am not allowed to make changes on authorization service. Looking for a possibility around cypress.

Comment: Add the code you tried.

Comment: I have just added

Comment: Hi @AlapanDas If you don't mind, can you check it pls out, I added the code I wrote as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the option `followRedirect` to `cy.request` it'll ignore the first 302 response and pick up on the final resolution instead.

```js
cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: Cypress.env('SERVER_URL'),
    failOnStatusCode: false,
    headers: {
      'Cookie': '...coookies...'
    },
    followRedirect: true, // <-- here
});
```